# Any Synaptics driver for HP 255 G2?

Tags: touchpad, hp, synaptics

Does anyone know how I can rectify the problem of not being able to use my touch pad at all on my HP 255 G2?
I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have to use a USB mouse, which is tiresome when I am not at a desk.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but the touchpad works if I boot the laptop after disconnecting the power cable, unplugging the battery and waiting for a while. The touchpad stops working if I shut down the laptop, but works still after a reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please do not post comments or "me too" notes in the answer space. If you have the same problem you can mark this question as a favorite (click on the star icon on the left side of the question) and you'll be notified whenever there is new activity on it through your profile page. If your question is different, feel free to open a new one by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) link on the top right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many other suggestions to get my touchpad and mouse buttons working, and nearly gave up. Then another issue led me to disable Secureboot, and suddenly Ubuntu recognised the trackpad and it started working.

However, I think you may have to do this before installing the OS. As soon as the computer starts, press Escape (for me at least but might be F10 or F2). In the menu at the top, go to System Configuration, then look for Secure Boot and disable it, and/or enable Legacy support. See https://www.daossoft.com/bios-tips/how-to-disable-secure-boot-on-hp-laptop-ultrabook.html for more information.